# How to integrate LinkedIn authorization from OAuth.io with Firebase

Tags: android, oauth, firebase, linkedin-api, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble integrating LinkedIn authorization from OAuth .io with Firebase on Android.

I am able to authenticate my user through LinkedIn, and OAuth .io is able to save the token into the Firebase database (on the application table not the system table, yet).

But when I pass the received token to Firebase as shown on the code below, firebase replies with an error.

```
        oauth.popup("linkedin2", new OAuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinished(OAuthData data) {
            String token = data.token;

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(token);
        }
```

The error I get is:

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The
>   custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Beta Test did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, why dont you do the normal authentication with either

Facebook 
Twitter
GitHub
Persona
Email/Password

And then after successful signing ask the user to retrieve their data by signing in to their linkedIn account.